# OpenCV Python converting color-space image to YCbCr

Tags: python, image, opencv, color-space, format-conversion

I need convert an image from BGR to YCbCr in Python using OpenCV.
I have an image with size/resolution 512x512, but when the image is opened, the size is 128x128.

I'm doing:

```
image = cv2.imread(imageName, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Could you try rephrasing this question? I am not sure about what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem:

If you look at the docs for [imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), the function takes an integer flag called [imreadmodes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80). This flag seems to accept information about resizing the image, rather than changing color spaces.

#### The solution:

I believe you are looking for the [cv2.cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) function which uses a [flag](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) to determine the source and destination colorspaces.

Both flags are simple integer enumerations. I assume the imread function is simply doing the best it can with the wrong type of flag.

You probably want to do something like:

```
BGRImage = cv2.imread(imageName)
YCrCbImage = cv2.cvtColor(BGRImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
```